# Linked List get method using recursive method

Tags: java

I was trying to design a get method for a linked list.
It takes an int position as an argument and it returns the list element at the given position(position starts at zero).

I think my logic is right, but doesn't compile. Could anyone point out what I have done wrong in here?

```
abstract public class AbstractListNode {

    abstract public Object first ( );
    abstract public AbstractListNode rest ( );
    abstract public boolean isEmpty ( );
    abstract public int size( );
    abstract public Object get(int index);
    // Every other list-processing method goes here.
}

class NonemptyListNode extends AbstractListNode {

    private Object myFirst;
    private AbstractListNode myRest;

    // cons in Scheme.
    public NonemptyListNode (Object first, AbstractListNode rest) {
        myFirst = first;
        if (rest == null) {
        myRest = new EmptyListNode ( );
        } else {
        myRest = rest;
        }
    }

    public NonemptyListNode (Object first) {
        this (first, new EmptyListNode ( ));
    }

    // car in Scheme.
    public Object first ( ) {
        return myFirst;
    }

    // cdr in Scheme.
    public AbstractListNode rest ( ) {
        return myRest;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty ( ) {
    return false;
    }

    public int size ( ) {
        return 1+myRest.size();
    }

    public Object get(int index){
        if(index+1 > this.size())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Out of Range");
        else if(index == 0){
            return myFirst;
        }
        else{
            index = index-1;
            AbstractListNode l = this.myRest;
            l.get(index);
        }          
    }
}

class EmptyListNode extends AbstractListNode {

    public EmptyListNode ( ) {

    }

    public Object first ( ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("There is no 'first' value stored in an EmptyListNode.");
    }

    public AbstractListNode rest ( ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("No elements follow an EmptyListNode.");
    }

    public boolean isEmpty ( ) {
        return true;
    }

    public int size( ) {
        return 0;
    }

    public Object get(int index){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Out of Range");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're getting a compilation error, you should really say what it is and where it's coming up... so that we don't have to copy the whole of your code and try to compile it ourselves.

Comment: _I think my logic is right, but doesn't compile_ The compiler tells you exactly which row and column have errors and which errors your code does have, so please paste it here.

Comment: Sorry about that. I got an error at "get method" in NonemptyListNode class.

Comment: It says: Multiple markers at this line (1)This method must return a result of thype Object. (2)implements AbstractListNode.get

Answer (score 3):

> I got an error at get method in NonemptyListNode

The error is that you don't have the return statement:

```
public Object get(int index){
    if(index+1 > this.size())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Out of Range");
    else if(index == 0){
        return myFirst;
    }
    else{
        index = index-1;
        AbstractListNode l = this.myRest;
        l.get(index);
        /*
         * here you should have a return statement, if this else block 
         * gets executed, no returns will be found. 
         */   
    }          
}
```

Comment: It looks like both if and else statement should have return statements. Thank you for all the answers and suggestions.